# Most Pythonic way to format sequences into a string?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have a sequence `urls = spam, eggs, foo, bar`, and I want to format them into a string like `'blogs “spam”, “eggs”, “foo”, and “bar” are not owned by primary “monty”'`.

Now there are loads and loads of inefficient ways I can think of to accomplish this, but what is the most pythonic? Right now I’ve got

```
'blogs {0}, and “{1}” are not owned by primary “{primary}”'.format(
    ', '.join('“' + url + '”' for url in urls[:-1]), urls[-1], primary='monty')
```

which feels clunky and of course doesn't work on `len(urls)` < `3`.

Comment: You can use `{1!r}` instead of `“{1}”` to get automatic (straight) double quotes around the strings (if that's what they are). Actually, you don't need the argument numbers and can leave them out since you're using them sequentially. All that will simplify it a bit.

Comment: any way to use curly quotes? This is for UI presentation, after all

Comment: Not without more code. I think most users would understand non-curly quotes just fine—it's the 21th century and a computer, not a publication.

Comment: You could put the formatting logic in a separate function and call it...which would be worthwhile if you're going to need to do it often enough.